# MySQL if variable then show results + specific result

Tags: mysql, case-when

Table clients

```
ID     |   Name    | start_Date          |  Future
1          John      20-02-2014 15:00:00     0
2          Maria     20-02-2014 15:00:00     0
3          Stack     21-02-2014 15:00:00     1
4          Google    21-02-2014 15:00:00     0
```

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients
```

Obviously this will get all clients, but I want to display the clients according to the `Future` variable. When `Future` variable is set the clients can only show from the `start_Date` to further.

If I change my query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE (NOW() >= start_Date OR start_Date IS NULL
       OR start_Date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

This will get me:

```
ID     |   Name    | start_Date          |  Future
1          John      20-02-2014 15:00:00      0
2          Maria     20-02-2014 15:00:00      0
```

But the output I expect is:

```
ID     |   Name    | start_Date          |  Future
1          John      20-02-2014 15:00:00     0
2          Maria     20-02-2014 15:00:00     0
4          Google    21-02-2014 15:00:00     0
```

I don't want to show

```
3          Stack     21-02-2014 15:00:00      1
```

because the variable `Future` is set to `1` and it can only be shown tomorrow (21-02-2014 15:00:00).
So, finally, I've come up with this without success:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE CASE WHEN Future = 1 THEN (NOW() >= start_Date OR start_Date IS NULL
       OR start_Date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients
WHERE future = 0
OR (future = 1 
    AND (NOW() >= start_Date 
         OR start_Date IS NULL 
         OR start_Date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: This one solved my issue I just had to add: `WHERE future = 0 OR future IS NULL OR (future = 1...)`. I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

why  not use this

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM clients
 WHERE future = 0
```